# Use distances calculate by vtkDistancePolyDataFilter

Tags: c++, mesh, vtk

I am new to VTK. I have the following snippet of code to calculate the vertex to vertex distances between two surface meshes using vtkDistancePolyDataFilter.

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkDistancePolyDataFilter> Normal_distances = vtkSmartPointer<vtkDistancePolyDataFilter>::New();
Normal_distances->SetInput(testSample );
Normal_distances->SetInput(1,bestModelReconstruction);
Normal_distances->SignedDistanceOff();
Normal_distances->Update();
```

I would like to access the distances in the output "Normal_distances" so I can calculate the mean values of the distances. Could someone help with a quick way to achieve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have not personally used this filter, but typically in vtk you access the results of a filter via the `GetOutput()` (or something similar depending on the version) member function.

[Here](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/PolyData/DistancePolyDataFilter) is an example of how to use a `vtkDistancePolyDataFilter`. In this case, it appears that the output will be a `vtkPolyData` with the computed distances used for the scalar
values of the points.

From the example:

```
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapper =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
  mapper->SetInputConnection( distanceFilter->GetOutputPort() );
  mapper->SetScalarRange(
    distanceFilter->GetOutput()->GetPointData()->GetScalars()->GetRange()[0],
    distanceFilter->GetOutput()->GetPointData()->GetScalars()->GetRange()[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks A.E. Drew. I think my problem has more to do with which type i can use to extract the output.

Comment: I mean something similar to mapper in your example A.E. Drew

Comment: Solved my problem: First convert from **vtkDistancePolyDataFilter** to  **vtkPolyData** Then the rest is the usual pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem: First convert from `vtkDistancePolyDataFilter` to `vtkPolyData`Then the rest is the usual pipeline.